# How to create two rectangles side by side in a drawable - xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, background, rectangles

So I know how to create a rectangle using a drawable as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 
<stroke
  android:width="2dp"
  android:color="#FFFFFF" />
 
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
 
<gradient
  android:angle="270"
  android:centerColor="#99CCCC"
  android:endColor="#99CCCC"
  android:startColor="#99CCCC" />

</shape>
```

Is there any way to make it so that I can have 2 Rectangles next to each other.

They both need to be in the same drawable file as this drawable will be set as the background of a button.

Expected output - Horizontal
[Horizontal Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5urWZ.png)

I'm also going to want to be able to make vertical ones:
[Vertical Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5NJW.png)

So each of them are all in one image, but in reality they will all be in their own drawables, 1 drawable for 1 rectangle, 1 for 2 and 1 for 3.

Cheers

Comment: show me your expected output.

Comment: Can't show you the expected output if I don't have a solution

Comment: @Nitrogen you can draw expected output in an online photo editor or something similar

Comment: Yes I can. Give me a sec

Comment: @dragoon
Hoping to make drawables containing something like above, also added some context. Cheers